# Is It Possible to get the media content from Sdcard through media.store method

Tags: java, android

I am currently working in sdcard detection in android I have doubt shall we get the media content from sdcard through media.store method. Please answer me.

Comment: Read [the official document](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage) to find the suitable use case for you. You usually don't need to worry about sdcard detection nowadays.

Comment: What do you consider to be 'sdcard detection'?

Comment: Thank you for your reply I am Preparing one media app in that I need sdcard content to play for this only I am asking whether media store help to get the media content from sdcard